# RubyMine Debugger not pausing correctling

Tags: rubymine

Using the debugger breaks the application just fine as it should. However a problem has started occuring, now when typing in the interactive console, the debugger seems to continue executing, and also ignoring any further breakpoints set in RubyMine!

Anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Could you please specify which RubyMine version you're using? Does the same happen in 2023.3 EAP as well?

Comment: surely. i'm using RubyMine 2023.2.4

Not running EAP.. Perhaps i should try  Just hardly seems a bug this critical is only resolved in EAP


EDIT: Just tried the EAP and i still have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a multi step solution.

1. Uninstall ruby-debug-ide `gem uninstall ruby-debug-ide`
2. Install rubymine EAP [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/nextversion/)
3. Let RubyMine EAP install `ruby-debug-ide` when debugging